# Um looping não termina para começar outro. Como resolver? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá, sou novo no fórum e ainda estou aprendendo a usar a interface. Se eu postei no lugar errado ou qualquer coisa assim, me desculpem. Criei uma conta para fazer uma pergunta a respeito de um problema que está me incomodando bastante. Estou fazendo um programa em python 3 que pega um arquivo Fasta e faz uma lista das "extensões" das sequências genômicas. O problema é que numa parte do código, mais precisamente nessa função, eu não consigo fazer com que o outro **for** comece para dar o resultado (no caso, a id do maior número, ou seja, do de maior extensão na sequência genômica). O primeiro for fica num looping eterno e eu não sei tirar ele disso.

```py
def identifiers():
  lista = []
  for record in SeqIO.parse(fasta, "fasta"):
    lista.append(len(record))
  for record in SeqIO.parse(fasta, "fasta"):
    if len(record) == lista_sort[-1]:
      print(record.id)
```

Alguém sabe como solucionar isso?

Comment: Matheus, coloque tambem o conteudo da variavel `fasta`e qual o resultado esperado com o codigo.

Comment: Não consegui fazer upload do arquivo. Há algum meio de fazer isso no próprio site?

Answer (score 0):

A variável `fasta` está definida em algum lugar fora da função?
Encontrei o seguinte exemplo:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
for record in SeqIO.parse("example.fasta", "fasta"):
    print(record.id)
```

Pelo que entendi, o primeiro argumento de SeqIO.parse deve ser um nome de arquivo ou uma variável equivalente ao nome do arquivo.
Se seu arquivo se chamar fasta.fasta, por exemplo, tente usar:

```
def identifiers():
  lista = []
  for record in SeqIO.parse("fasta.fasta", "fasta"):
    lista.append(len(record))
  for record in SeqIO.parse("fasta.fasta", "fasta"):
    if len(record) == lista_sort[-1]:
      print(record.id)
```

Comment: Esqueci de dizer. A variável está, sim, definida globalmente. O porém é que o primeiro "for" não faz um "break" quando termina de executar e não deixa o outro "for" começar. Enfim, o resultado não sai.

Comment: Matheus, conseguiu fazer rodar?